# My created equals() and hashcode() are not doing anything

Tags: java, equals, hashset

In my program I have a class called Cell, defined like so:

```
public class Cell {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Cell (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object o) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (o instanceof Cell) {
            Cell other = (Cell) o;
            result = (this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y)
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override        
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = x;
        result = 31 * result + y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have a Grid class, like so (many methods cut out and variable names simplified):

```
public class Grid {
    private Set<Cell> cellArray;

    public Grid() {
        cellArray = new HashSet<Cell>();
    }

    public Set<Cell> getCellArray() {
        return cellArray;
    }

    public void addCellArray(Cell cell) {
        cellArray.add(cell)
    }
}
```

In my main body of code, I take in a grid object, like so:

```
public class Controller {
    private Grid grid;
    public Controller (Grid grid) (
        this.grid = grid;
```

Then, I have a series of loops that look like this:

```
private set<Cell> cellArray = grid.getCellArray();

boolean endLoop = false;
 do {
    x = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    y = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (cellArray.contains(new Cell(x, y+i))) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        cellArray.add(new Cell(x, y+i));
    }
    endLoop = true;
} while(!endLoop);
```

I'm aware it's a very messy, with too much instantiation going on (and if anyone has pointers to make it cleaner, feel free to point them out) - however, the main issue is the fact that the first for loop is meant to check if the cellArray contains the items - it doesn't seem to be doing this.

There's no error message, no null pointer or anything like that. I've tried debugging it and have seen it compare two cells with identical x and y values, without proceeding to the continue statement to start the do while loop again.

I am assuming this is because even though they have identical values, they are different 'objects' and so aren't coming back as equal.

How could I fix this and get them to equate to one another if their values are the same?

Comment: `private set<Cell> cellArray = Grid.getCellArray();`..`getCellArray` is not static within `Grid` class. This will show compile time error.

Comment: Why would it need to be static? I'm not getting any compile time errors.

Comment: How can you call `non-static` method of a class without creating its instance?

Comment: Apologies - I see what you meant. I've cut out A LOT of code for brevity. I do have an instance of it in the constructor of this class (which acts as a controller). I'll edit my question now to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `continue` statement continues the inner `for`-loop (which is quite useless here). You probably want to continue the outer loop: `continue outerLoop;`, with the label `outerLoop:` put in front of `do {`.

As [the Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) states, the `contains` method should rely on your `equals` method, so object equality should work as you expect it.

Comment: That's ticket. Had no idea you could label loops. Now, to tidy up the damn code. Thanks!